# How to count the total number of file in directory assets angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a folder in assets folder named file_json. I want to count how many files are in that folder in the component ts. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done with angular. Angular build is just bunch of html, css and JavaScript that runs on the browser. And the browser cannot read folder directory.